# Usage of same PKI for peer identity and TLS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In HyperLedger Fabric why can't we use the same PKI for Peer Identity and as well as TLS !?

Comment: could you elaborate your query?

Comment: In HyperLedger, for every peer node they do have a Digital cert(.pem) and private key to identify themself. later when i got into tls part, came across another server.crt server.key files here why cant we can't we use the same .pem and private key for tls too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can use the same key/cert pair for both signing and TLS (the X509 cert will need to be issued with all of the usage and extended usage attributes required for both cases).

This, however, is not a recommended security practice.  Best practice is to follow a "separation of concerns" when it comes to issuing the crypto material / identities.  So for our samples we chose to adopt these best practices.

An example might be that you want to use one of the major 3rd party CAs (Symantec, DigiCert, Certicom, etc) to issue your TLS certificates but then use your own CA to issue the enrollment material.

Answer (score 0):

@Karthick V

Thanks for updating the question

I hope you are using `cryptogen` Tool thats why you are able to see extra `tls folder` along with

- msp/keystore
- msp/signcerts

Well in Fabric you can do three ways

- without TLS
- with TLS
- With mutual TLS

cryptogen is giving you the freedom to go with either with TLS or with TLS

If you familiar with Fabric-CA while enrolling we will mention a tag `profile: "tls"` so fabric-ca will be notified that certs are going to use in TLS mode